# Edit Page for Ecommerce Site PHP

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am having trouble getting my edit page for my ecommerce site to work.

You can log in here: http://lpehrson.mydevryportfolio.com/webdev/admin_login.php
The user name is test@test.com and the password is test.

The edit page is here: the edit page is at the same source at edit.php

As you can see there are a lot of errors. I can't find where I went wrong in the code.

Here is a link to the website files here: http://lpehrson.mydevryportfolio.com/webdev/LPehrsonILab4.zip

If you could help that would be great.

Comment: Please dont put anything **there**. Put every thing **here** so we can see it at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are pretty straight forward. Your include paths are wrong which is why your getting those errors, and your database username is still using an @localhost, which wont work on a live site. You need to call the right include directory, probably /includes/file.php would do it. or ../includes, i dont know how you have the directories structured, but you can figure that part out. As for accessing the DB you'll need to get server username , password and probably the database name from your hosting provider, make those changes and you'll be on the right track.

Comment: I have made changes and now I am getting a different error. I call the user name and password in the database_admin.php file.  http://lpehrson.mydevryportfolio.com/webdev/homeworkhelp.zip

http://lpehrson.mydevryportfolio.com/webdev/edit.php - edit page